# Replacing href text with something else using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, href

How can I replace the "echo ucwords($row2[mainImage1]);" in the href attribute of the  tag below with the "echo $row2[selectionThumb3];" from the src attribute of the  tag below using Javascript?

Here is how my code looks:

```
    <img class="thumbNotSelected" src="../images/ThumbSelection/<?php echo $row2[selectionThumb3]; ?>.jpg"  />

<div class="mainImage magnify">
     <a href="../images/MainImage/<?php echo ucwords($row2[mainImage1]); ?>.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="<?=$row2[name]?>">
           <img class="mainImage small" src="../images/MainImage/<?php echo $row2[mainImage1]; ?>.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Adding my current Javascript:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', {
click: function(){
$('.mainImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('ThumbSelection','MainImage').replace('selectionThumb','mainImage')); //here I replace the src of the Main Image to match the selected thumbnail.
var $this = $(this),
  index = $this.index();
$("#thumbs img").removeClass('thumbSelected');
 $this.addClass('thumbSelected');

}});
```

There are several thumbs that the user can click on. The main image loads the corresponding picture after clicking on its Thumb. However, the  (used for a lightbox) never changes to adapt to the new loaded picture and the lightbox always uses the same image instead of the one the user has clicked on.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're using JavaScript, show the rendered mark-up of the page ('view source' in the browser), and then clarify what you're asking us to help with.

Comment: Sorry, just realized it wasn't clear. I added the JS and additional info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the js below you would be dynamically changing the href of your link to the same exact path of the image loaded. Let me know if it works

```
 $('#thumbs').delegate('img', {
    click: function(){
        $('.mainImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('ThumbSelection','MainImage').replace('selectionThumb','mainImage'));
        $('.mainImage a').attr('href',$(this).attr('src').replace('ThumbSelection','MainImage').replace('selectionThumb','mainImage'));
        var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index();
        $("#thumbs img").removeClass('thumbSelected');
        $this.addClass('thumbSelected');

    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.mainImage a').attr('href', $('.thumbNotSelected').attr('src'));`

Should do what you need.